# IntelliJ IDEA Scala - reformat file: put case classes at the beginning

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm using the shortcut to `reformat file` my .scala files. After that, the `types` are at the beginning, then come `functions` and the `case class` at the bottom.

I would like to change the order when formatting to have `types`, `case classes` and then `functions`.

I cannot find where should I set this, any ideas?

PS: IntelliJ IDEA Community 2019.2

Answer (score 1):

You can change the arrangement rules when formatting from here: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Scala` and then go to the `Arrangement` tab.

If you don't see Scala as a language you have to install [Scalafmt](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-scala-formatter.html) plugin.

The official documentation from Intellij is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#rearrange_code).

Comment: I've found what you said but the `case` modifier is disabled always...